# Using builtin types (double, int, etc.) in a C++ namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces, typedef, swig, built-in

Can I make builtin types like `int` and `double` available in a C++ namespace?

```
#include <complex>

typedef int my_int;

namespace my_namespace {
  namespace std = ::std;  // Works
  using ::my_int;         // Works

  using ::int;            // Fails: "expected unqualified-id before 'int'"
  typedef ::int int;      // Fails: "expected unqualified-id before 'int'"
}

typedef int out::int;     // Fails: "expected unqualified-id before 'int'"

my_namespace::my_int x;            // Works
my_namespace::std::complex<int> c; // Works

// I would like to use this:
my_namespace::int x2;    // Fails: "expected unqualified-id before 'int'"
```

I suspect that this is due to a language limitation that forbids the use of qualified identifiers with keywords in them (`int` in this case) but am hoping that there is some way of exposing these.

### Use Case

I am trying to use namespaces to organize types so that an external tool ([SWIG](http://www.swig.org/)) can appropriately wrap functions in another language. For example:

```
void one_two(int &x, int &y) { x = 1; y = 2; }
```

In the target language, this could be wrapped as a function that mutates its arguments `one_two(x, y)`, or a function that returns the output `x, y = one_two()`.  I would like some way of "annotating" the arguments to provide [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) with the intended usage.  The cleanest option with the current [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/) implementation is to use a namespace to differentate between the two uses: thus the output version `x, y = one_two()` could be denoted::

```
void one_two(out::int &x, out::int &y) { x = 1; y = 2; }
```

if I could somehow make `out::int` a synonym for `int`.  (This approach works fine with user-defined types.)

Comment: What language are you targeting with SWIG here? Many of the target languages make it easy to insert this sort of "strong typedef" within the interface.

Comment: @Flexo: Python, but I don't see how that will help. The goal is C++ code that can automatically be wrapped. I need to provide clues for SWIG - so either modifying the name (``OUTPUT`` instead of ``x`` which is not undesirable because of kwargs) or use a typedef.  The ``out`` namespace is clean, but would be even better if it also worked for builtin types, which I think is not possible.  See [this thread](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/message.php?msg_id=29534918).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`int` and friends are keywords in the language. They are not names in the global namespace; they are not names at all as far as the language is concerned. Qualifying them with `::` is an error. Trying to name any variable `int` is also an error. Specifically, see 2.1 paragraph 1 in C++03, and 2.12 paragraph 1 in C++11 (the text is the same):

```
The identifiers shown in Table 3 are reserved for use as keywords (that is, they
are unconditionally treated as keywords in phase 7):
[ ... ]
int
```